# Pytorch error mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, training-data

I receive this error. Whereas the size of my input image is  [3072,2,2], so I flatten the image by the following code, however, I received this error:

`mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (6144x2 and 12288x512)`

my code:

```
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(12288 ,512) 
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 3)  
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = torch.flatten(x,0)
        
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out

model = NeuralNet().to(device)

# Train the model
total_step = len(my_dataloader)
for epoch in range(5):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(my_dataloader):  
        # Move tensors to the configured device
        images = images.to(device)
        print(type(images))
        labels = labels.to(device)
        
        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know which error is happening?

```
mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (6144x2 and 12288x512)
```

you can't multiply a `(m x n)` matrix with `(p x n)`.

```
your error : (6144x2) * (12288x512)
```

It needs to be `(m x n)` with `(n x p)`. This "inner" dimensions need to be the same (number of columns of left matrix = number of rows of right matrix).

> **Then : ---> out = torch.flatten(x,0) change your image [3072,2,2] to**
> **[3072*2,2] = [6144,2] (not  this [16288]) ,**

> **and    matrix [6144,2] and [2,512] shapes can be multiplied**

Answer (score 0):

First, your in-features of the linear layer is not correct. The in-feature should be the last dim of your input. In this case, it should be `nn.Linear(2,512)`

```
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2 ,512) 
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 3)  
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = torch.flatten(x,0)
        
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
```

Based on [PyTorch document](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html) the `torch.flatten(x,0)` return shape of `[3072*2,2]` if you want to have the shape of `[12288]` as you linear in-features, you should use the `torch.flatten(input, start_dim=0, end_dim=- 1)`

```
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(12288 ,512) 
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 3)  
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = torch.flatten(x)
        
        out = self.fc1(x,start_dim=0, end_dim=- 1)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
```